# C# - websocket-sharp - Proxy connects to the wrong port

Tags: c#, proxy

[image]

This occurs when I had simultaneous connections to a server, for some reason it connects to the wrong port. The code I'm using to set the proxies:

```
agarSocket.SetProxy("http://" + proxyAddress, "", "");
```

This is the code which initates the connection to the agar.io server:

```
Client agarClient = new Client("Bot.exe");
agarClient.Connect(agarServer.Host, agarServer.Token, proxyAddress);
```

Note: Yes, it's an agar.io bot I've been developing in C#.

Comment: 1) What does the screenshot actually display? The remote server to connect to as the client?
2) Why do you use proxyAddress on both SetProxy() and Connect()? It doesn't make sence to connect to the proxy as the client using the proxy itself as the proxy.
3) Is the port changing each time? (I don't think so)
4) Have you tried to explicitly set the port every where?

Comment: I'm assuming your problem is rellated with the connection to agar.io which is handle by your hand-craft Client class which we don't have access?

Comment: The screenshot shows the correct port 8080 and then a failure to connect to 15299. The connection is handle by SetProxy.

Answer (score 0):

The end of your urls contains extra characters

In your case it end with \r (Carriage Return)

If you have a debugger available USE IT, log could help you as a starting point to know where to look but it will never replace a debugger.
A debugger allow you to look at value at anytime and it does try to format value to help you understard.
I'm using VisualStudio for Desktop and it clearly display the wrong character (`"http://localhost:8080\r"`)